# Multi language, intelligent link conversion

Tags: umbraco

I'm pretty new to Umbraco, so my question may turn out to be pretty simple, but I wasn't able to find any simple guide on it online.

I'm building a simple website with one domain and structure as follows

```
Content

- en
-- products
-- contacts

- cs
-- produkty
-- kontakty
```

and so on. My first question is: since I want to accomplish some nice results in SEO, I need to (i) assign meta language to contents of "en" and "cs" nodes, as well as some keywords. How should I do this?

Second: Say that in the future, I decide to add a new language, ex. Russian. So what I would need to do is to make a copy of the "en" node and its contents while the links included in the newly created copy should be rewritten to point at the copy and not the original (original would be /en/anotherpage, which should be rewritten to /ru/anotherpage). Is this possible?

Thanks,
Ondrej

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build the content structure as a single root node and then have multiple Language homepage nodes directly beneath the content root.

To assign a language, you could create a custom datatype that simply displays all the .Net cultures, e.g. en-GB, fr-FR etc. Include that data type as a field on the language homepage document type and then output this value in the markup on the homepage and each descendant.

In the Language homepage document type, you can add a textstring property called 'umbracoUrlName'. You can then use this property to override the Url name. E.g. So you could call the page www.domain.com/en/ instead of www.domain.com/en/english-home/

With regards to duplicating the site at a later date, this is a difficult one. If the links are created using data types like the media picker and uComponent's multi node tree picker, then you will have no option but to inherit the links from the copied branch. However, if the links are created dynamically in the Razor or XSLT, then you should be able to make the links relative to the Language homepage or the current page. E.g. in XSLT getting the children of the parent language homepage would be something like `$currentPage/ancestors-or-self::* [@level = '2']/child::*` .  In other words you can avoid hard coding links by using a clever bit of relative traversal.

Comment: The SEO guidelines state that you should provide "hreflang" meta for each language on each of the URL's. This solution gives you only one meta tag per language.
Example: https://play.google.com/store

Comment: @Adinp I'm not sure of the point you are making. Using the approach I outline above you can still add the language meta `<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en-ie" hreflang="en-ie" />`. Could you expand on your point please?

Comment: As you can read here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en

"If you have multiple language versions of a URL, each language page must identify all language versions, including itself. "

That means that if you have N languages that every page should have N <link hreflang="" /> tags. 

You can see the example on https://play.google.com/store (view source of the page, it has over 20 hreflangs).

How to achieve what Google Play store has in Umbraco?

Comment: @Adinp Sure, I'm familiar with the documentation. Why would my solution prevent you from achieving what you require? In the header you would simply traverse up the content tree and then down again and output the sibling pages as hreflang links. Of course this all relies on the site structures being identical. If they're not, then it wouldn't be possible either way.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a good start on creating multilingual sites in Umbraco

http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/running-multi-lingual-sites-under-a-single-domain

If you was to create a Russian version in the future you would do exactly what you have mentioned above, its that easy.

Comment: I read this, but this will still result in the links that are included in the copied page pointing to the original language and not to the copy.

Answer (score 0):

To set the language meta data I would store this in a property on the langauge root node eg: /en/ to get the language page property from any page:

```
var langNode = new Node(int.Parse(node.Path.Split(',')[1]));
langNode.GetProperty("languageCode");
```

As for copying the English version to the Russian version and fixing all the links, I'm not aware of anything in umbraco to help you with this, you could write something yourself to find all the links and node references and fix them. you could use the [relations API](http://blog.hendyracher.co.uk/umbraco-relation-api/) to keep track of what was copied from where to where. You'll need to be aware that you could end up copying nodes more than once.

If you don't have too much data, manually fixing links may be quicker.